# Stop Apache mod_rewrite affecting Redirect rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /test/example-1 /test/example-2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want the redirect to happen without mod_rewrite interfering with it, but at the moment when you hit `/test/example-1` it redirects to `/test/example-2?_url=example-1`.

Is there any way to stop the query parameter from the rewrite rule getting append to the redirect URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rewrite rule as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(example-1|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But in general you shouldn't mix `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite` rules. Your code can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /example-1[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ example-2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Only thing is that there could be lots of Redirects, I was kinda hoping there might be a way to do just have Apache process the redirects before mod_rewrite does anything? Save having any duplication etc.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, I should just use mod_rewrite for everything.